# Modify array key when sent to str_replace PHP

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I'm trying to make use of html templates in my project and it's working so far but to make the templates easier to use I would like to use {} to denote the field areas. Like this:

```
//tplCall.html
<div id="{CustID}">
    <div class="callname">{Name}</div>
    <div class="calladdress">{Address}</div>
</div>
```

The following works fine:

```
$tmpCall = file_get_contents("templates/tplCall.html");
$tmpdata = get_object_vars($thiscall);
$htmlout = str_replace(array_keys($tmpdata),array_values($tmpdata),$tmpCall);
echo $htmlout;
```

But obviously leaves the {} intact. I would like to do something like the following but I get an array to string error. How can I add the {} to the key portion before it gets sent to str_replace?

```
$tmpCall = file_get_contents("templates/tplCall.html");
$tmpdata = get_object_vars($thiscall);
$htmlout = str_replace("{" . array_keys($tmpdata) . "}",array_values($tmpdata),$tmpCall);
echo $htmlout;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify each element of `array_keys($tmpdata)` explicitly:

```
$keys = array_map(function($v) { return '{' . $v . '}'; }, array_keys($tmpdata));
// also there's no need to apply `array_values` 
// as `str_replace` does not care about keys.
$htmlout = str_replace($keys, $tmpdata, $tmpCall);
```